# Live smart contract problem

Tags: anchor, web3.js

https://github.com/jimvdH/react/blob/main/src/utils/anchorClient.js
Here is the code i am trying to use.

I am trying to connect to a live smart contract https://solscan.io/account/Goats192jeQq3r2sn8pe69LyJtisLMfEoq8LyDienct1#anchorProgramIDL and interact with it. In this case use the withdraw function.

Whenever I run this code I get the following error in the web console.Calling the withdraw function when pressing the shoot button.

provider.ts:104 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'publicKey')
at w.send (provider.ts:104:31)
at Object.withdraw (rpc.ts:25:38)
at Object.withdraw (anchorClient.js:86:32)
at async submitJoke (JokeArena.js:18:9)

And when I click on the provider.ts error log I get the following
Could not load content for http://localhost:1234/__parcel_source_root/node_modules/@project-serum/src/provider.ts (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE)

Hope someone can help me!
Thank you in advance!

In the anchorClient.js I am running the following code

````
const privateKey =[54,32,etc];
const wallet1 = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(privateKey));
const withdraw = async (wallet, network) => {
    const pairAddress = new PublicKey('4RsEwVg3gw6MX1PrXkdXJLwatUDDxK5o9hPFJP8keYS3');
    const pairAuthorityAddress = new PublicKey('GWJ26hQgem1t64E9HnfL23KRbBBC9H6rUCXqvPmx9SE2');
    const program = await getProgram(wallet, network);
    const amount = new BN(99);
  
   const tx =await program.rpc.withdraw(amount, {
        accounts: {
            pair: pairAddress,
            pairAuthority: pairAuthorityAddress,
            owner: wallet1.publicKey,
            systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        },
        signers: [wallet1], 
    });
    console.log(tx);
    console.log('Withdrawal successful');
} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to tell from the limited code, but it looks like there's a problem with `wallet` not being a real signer.

Since it looks like `wallet1` is a keypair, and we don't know what `wallet` is, try using `wallet1` everywhere by changing `program`'s creation to:

```
    const program = await getProgram(wallet1, network);
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to give the wallet parameter to the signer so that was the reason it didn't work.